# Codeigniter - Only allow the user to delete from database if the user created the entry in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a delete button/link hooked up which will delete the entry from the database.

My view file:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() . "profile/delete_entry/" . $data->pid; ?>">Delete</a>
```

My controller:

```
 function delete_entry() {
    $this->session->userdata('uid')
    $this->load->model('model_entry');
    $pid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->model_entry->entry_delete($pid);
    $this->entries();
}
```

And finally, my model:

```
public function entry_delete($pid) {

    $this->db->where('pid', $pid);
    $this->session->userdata('uid')
    $this->db->delete('dayone_entries');

}
```

So, the link works. I can delete an entry from the database, without any problem.

However, I can also delete entries that the user didn't create. I can simply do that by replacing the `pid` of the entry (in the database) from the url and input some other pid and it will delete it, even though the user didn't create it.

How can ensure that only the user who created the pid can delete it?

My column in my table in my database:

```
pid, uid, time, entry
```

Comment: How does it know the user? Is it the uid?

Comment: The user id the uid which I get via `$this->session->userdata('uid')`

Comment: Ok thats all well and good, but you aren't using that session in your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "uid" is the id of the user who made it, you need to add another WHERE where uid equals the user id in session.

Comment: And you're probably getting the sessions user id like `$this->session->userdata('uid')`

Comment: I'm already getting their uid from the session. Forgot to put it up there. Edited. Thanks :)

Comment: Right, so...

`$whereConditions = array('pid' => $pid, 'uid' => $uid);
$this->db->where($whereConditions); `

Comment: I see now where the confusion is, `$this->session->userdata('uid')` just references the uid but doesn't check the database for the uid. So  `$uid=$this->session->userdata('uid')` and then as above `$whereConditions = array('pid' => $pid, 'uid' => $uid); $this->db->where($whereConditions);` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! It's solved now. I really really appreciate your answer :)